# nginx dont pass SSL parameter for default page

Tags: ssl, nginx, fastcgi

I am facing this weired issue.
After a long trial and error I concluded that. My nginx server  is not passing the SSL parameter to PHP if the user visits the Home page first time.

```
it works well if the user clicks some other links.
it works well when user first time visit other links.
it works well even for Home page second time.
```

To check please visit my site [test.jawabee.in](https://test.jawabee.in), here you can search for  [SSL_PROTOCOL] => TLSv1.2 which is absent if you visited home page first time.

To test again, kill your browser forcefully (from task manager)

Here is my nginx.comf.

```
 server {
    listen       443 ssl ;
    server_name  test.jawabee.in;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/jawabee;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.jawabee.in/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.jawabee.in/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.jawabee.in/chain.pem;
    ssl_session_cache off;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/testjawabee.template;
}
```

here is my testjawabee.template

```
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ (^\.|/\.) {
        return 403;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @elgg;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri @elgg;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
    location @elgg {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     /index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SSL_PROTOCOL $ssl_protocol;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    __elgg_uri=$uri&$args;
    }
```

Comment: you may get actual index.php as an `index` file, thus the nginx will chose the `location ~ \.php$` without a `SSL_PROTOCOL`.

Comment: thanks I tried that and it works.